# Ionic Cordova Build Android - Gradle fail

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, azure-devops, build.gradle

We are building azure DevOps pipeline for iOS and Android. It builds everything and but getting and error saying "An error occurred while running subprocess cordova" after taking 8-9 mins. I'm using the below Ionic command as part of the DevOps pipeline.

Cordova platform add android
cordova build android --nofetch

```
2018-12-03T15:17:27.8641072Z > ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
2018-12-03T15:17:29.7086284Z [15:17:29]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.1 
2018-12-03T15:17:29.7196684Z [15:17:29]  build dev started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:29.7961234Z [15:17:29]  clean started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:29.7970924Z [15:17:29]  clean finished in 1 ms 
2018-12-03T15:17:29.7972878Z [15:17:29]  copy started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:29.8680933Z [15:17:29]  deeplinks started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:29.9707450Z [15:17:29]  deeplinks finished in 103 ms 
2018-12-03T15:17:29.9710059Z [15:17:29]  transpile started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:35.2800497Z [15:17:35]  transpile finished in 5.31 s 
2018-12-03T15:17:35.2801948Z [15:17:35]  preprocess started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:35.2807465Z [15:17:35]  preprocess finished in 1 ms 
2018-12-03T15:17:35.2810624Z [15:17:35]  webpack started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:35.3953875Z [15:17:35]  copy finished in 5.60 s 
2018-12-03T15:17:40.2359365Z [15:17:40]  webpack finished in 4.96 s 
2018-12-03T15:17:40.2361747Z [15:17:40]  sass started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:41.4930311Z [15:17:41]  sass finished in 1.26 s 
2018-12-03T15:17:41.4932335Z [15:17:41]  postprocess started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:41.5006377Z [15:17:41]  postprocess finished in 8 ms 
2018-12-03T15:17:41.5008773Z [15:17:41]  lint started ... 
2018-12-03T15:17:41.5060709Z [15:17:41]  build dev finished in 11.79 s 

2018-12-03T15:17:44.9884111Z > cordova build android --verbose
2018-12-03T15:17:46.0046089Z No scripts found for hook "before_build".
2018-12-03T15:17:46.0198947Z No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
2018-12-03T15:17:46.0204839Z Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
2018-12-03T15:17:46.0237782Z Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
2018-12-03T15:17:46.0238262Z Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
2018-12-03T15:17:46.0874575Z PlatformApi successfully found for platform android
2018-12-03T15:17:46.0893604Z Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
2018-12-03T15:17:46.1016168Z Discovered plugin "mx.ferreyra.callnumber" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
2018-12-03T15:17:46.1275342Z No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
2018-12-03T15:17:46.1291010Z Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "mx.ferreyra.callnumber@0.0.2"
2018-12-03T15:17:51.3693302Z Running command: cmd "/s /c "D:\a\1\s\node_modules\.bin\npm.cmd install mx.ferreyra.callnumber@"0.0.2" --production --no-save""
2018-12-03T15:18:07.1241176Z Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "D:\a\1\s\node_modules\.bin\npm.cmd install mx.ferreyra.callnumber@"0.0.2" --production --no-save"
2018-12-03T15:18:12.3698789Z Copying plugin "D:\a\1\s\node_modules\mx.ferreyra.callnumber" => "D:\a\1\s\plugins\call-number"
2018-12-03T15:18:12.3760942Z Calling plugman.install on plugin "D:\a\1\s\plugins\call-number" for platform "android
2018-12-03T15:18:12.3797489Z Plugin "call-number" already installed on android.
2018-12-03T15:18:12.4439165Z No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_add".
2018-12-03T15:18:12.4440040Z Discovered plugin "mx.ferreyra.callnumber" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
2018-12-03T15:18:12.4650291Z No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
2018-12-03T15:18:12.4653439Z Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "mx.ferreyra.callnumber@0.0.2"
2018-12-03T15:18:17.6860183Z Running command: cmd "/s /c "D:\a\1\s\node_modules\.bin\npm.cmd install mx.ferreyra.callnumber@"0.0.2" --production --no-save""
2018-12-03T15:18:32.3787714Z Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "D:\a\1\s\node_modules\.bin\npm.cmd install mx.ferreyra.callnumber@"0.0.2" --production --no-save"
2018-12-03T15:18:38.2942299Z Copying plugin "D:\a\1\s\node_modules\mx.ferreyra.callnumber" => "D:\a\1\s\plugins\call-number"
2018-12-03T15:18:38.2942823Z Calling plugman.install on plugin "D:\a\1\s\plugins\call-number" for platform "android
2018-12-03T15:18:38.2943134Z Plugin "call-number" already installed on android.
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3131627Z No scripts found for hook "after_plugin_add".
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3158105Z Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in android platform
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3165248Z No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in android platform. Continuing...
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3320971Z Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at D:\a\1\s\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3698961Z Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3699508Z Merging and updating files from [www, platforms\android\platform_www] to platforms\android\assets\www
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3904379Z   mkdir platforms\android\assets\www\assets
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3904843Z   mkdir platforms\android\assets\www\assets\font
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3905098Z   mkdir platforms\android\assets\www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3905241Z   copy  www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\SEGOEUI.TTF platforms\android\assets\www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\SEGOEUI.TTF (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3916870Z   copy  www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\font-map-segoe-ui.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\font-map-segoe-ui.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3926657Z   copy  www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\font-map-unicode-segoe-ui.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\font-map-unicode-segoe-ui.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3929273Z   copy  www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\latest.woff platforms\android\assets\www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\latest.woff (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3936325Z   copy  www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\myfonts.me.txt platforms\android\assets\www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\myfonts.me.txt (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3942460Z   copy  www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\segoe-ui.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\font\Segoe-UI-Font\segoe-ui.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3952753Z   mkdir platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3955845Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\ionicons.eot platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\ionicons.eot (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3964499Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\ionicons.scss platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\ionicons.scss (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3971581Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\ionicons.svg platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\ionicons.svg (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3981569Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\ionicons.ttf platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\ionicons.ttf (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3998862Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\ionicons.woff platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\ionicons.woff (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.3999329Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\ionicons.woff2 platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\ionicons.woff2 (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4009215Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\noto-sans-bold.ttf platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\noto-sans-bold.ttf (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4022297Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\noto-sans-bold.woff platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\noto-sans-bold.woff (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4031908Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\noto-sans-regular.ttf platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\noto-sans-regular.ttf (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4044209Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\noto-sans-regular.woff platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\noto-sans-regular.woff (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4052009Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\noto-sans.scss platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\noto-sans.scss (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4057871Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-bold.ttf platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-bold.ttf (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4064510Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-bold.woff platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-bold.woff (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4071160Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-bold.woff2 platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-bold.woff2 (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4077520Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-light.ttf platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-light.ttf (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4084004Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-light.woff platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-light.woff (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4089000Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-light.woff2 platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-light.woff2 (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4095330Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-medium.ttf platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-medium.ttf (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4100912Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-medium.woff platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-medium.woff (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4108927Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-medium.woff2 platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-medium.woff2 (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4115737Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-regular.ttf platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-regular.ttf (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4121932Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-regular.woff platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-regular.woff (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4128338Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto-regular.woff2 platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto-regular.woff2 (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4134580Z   copy  www\assets\fonts\roboto.scss platforms\android\assets\www\assets\fonts\roboto.scss (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4139479Z   mkdir platforms\android\assets\www\assets\icon
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4142528Z   copy  www\assets\icon\favicon.ico platforms\android\assets\www\assets\icon\favicon.ico (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4148446Z   mkdir platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4154977Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\activity.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\activity.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4160448Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\card.jpeg platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\card.jpeg (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4166440Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\contact-us.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\contact-us.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4183087Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\fingerprint.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\fingerprint.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4188642Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\login-bg.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\login-bg.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4201517Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\login-logo.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\login-logo.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4207895Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\logo.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\logo.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4217919Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\MyAppMenuPageImg.jpeg platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\MyAppMenuPageImg.jpeg (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4224696Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\MyAppTouchPage.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\MyAppTouchPage.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4229742Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\MyApp.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\MyApp.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4235912Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\MyApp1.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\MyApp1.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4241525Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\touchId.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\touchId.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4247310Z   copy  www\assets\imgs\touch_ID.png platforms\android\assets\www\assets\imgs\touch_ID.png (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4254043Z   mkdir platforms\android\assets\www\build
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4265067Z   copy  www\build\main.css platforms\android\assets\www\build\main.css (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4269533Z   copy  www\build\main.css.map platforms\android\assets\www\build\main.css.map (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4275627Z   copy  www\build\main.js platforms\android\assets\www\build\main.js (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4282689Z   copy  www\build\main.js.map platforms\android\assets\www\build\main.js.map (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4312995Z   copy  www\build\polyfills.js platforms\android\assets\www\build\polyfills.js (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4313352Z   copy  www\build\sw-toolbox.js platforms\android\assets\www\build\sw-toolbox.js (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4313792Z   copy  www\build\vendor.js platforms\android\assets\www\build\vendor.js (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4358909Z   copy  www\build\vendor.js.map platforms\android\assets\www\build\vendor.js.map (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4414210Z   copy  www\index.html platforms\android\assets\www\index.html (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4419193Z   copy  www\manifest.json platforms\android\assets\www\manifest.json (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4443328Z   copy  www\service-worker.js platforms\android\assets\www\service-worker.js (new file)
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4474798Z Wrote out android application name "MyApp" to D:\a\1\s\platforms\android\res\values\strings.xml
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4556882Z android-versionCode not found in config.xml. Generating a code based on version in config.xml (0.0.1): 1
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4768677Z Wrote out Android package name "com.aafes.MyApp" to D:\a\1\s\platforms\android\src\com\aafes\MyApp\MainActivity.java
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4774349Z Updating icons at platforms\android\res
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4774645Z Updating splash screens at platforms\android\res
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4775050Z This app does not have additional resource files defined
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4775316Z Prepared android project successfully
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4820801Z Executing script found in plugin cordova-plugin-app-preferences for hook "after_prepare": plugins\cordova-plugin-app-preferences\bin\after_prepare.js
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4831670Z Resolving module name for q => q
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4832384Z Resolving module name for path => path
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4832846Z Resolving module name for elementtree => elementtree
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4835483Z Resolving module name for cordova => cordova
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4847380Z Resolving module name for cordova-lib/src/cordova/util => ../cordova/util
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4855237Z Resolving module name for fs => fs
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4885085Z Resolving module name for q => q
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4885460Z Resolving module name for path => path
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4887807Z Resolving module name for elementtree => elementtree
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4888212Z Resolving module name for cordova => cordova
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4888661Z Resolving module name for cordova-lib/src/cordova/util => ../cordova/util
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4889176Z Resolving module name for fs => fs
2018-12-03T15:18:38.4897111Z Resolving module name for plist => plist
2018-12-03T15:18:38.5166482Z Resolving module name for xcode => xcode
2018-12-03T15:18:38.5832848Z will push strings array {"name":"lang","titles":["English (US)","English (UK)"],"values":["en-us","en-gb"]}
2018-12-03T15:18:38.5857260Z android preferences file was successfully generated
2018-12-03T15:18:38.5992627Z No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
2018-12-03T15:18:51.7238115Z ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
2018-12-03T15:18:51.7238581Z JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
2018-12-03T15:18:51.7987537Z Running command: C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin\gradle.exe -p D:\a\1\s\platforms\android wrapper -b D:\a\1\s\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0145291Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0150855Z D:\a\1\s>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" setlocal
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0150940Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0208233Z D:\a\1\s>set DIRNAME=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\gradle\tools\gradle-4.10.2\bin\ 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0208289Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0208329Z D:\a\1\s>if "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\gradle\tools\gradle-4.10.2\bin\" == "" set DIRNAME=. 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0213526Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0214346Z D:\a\1\s>set APP_BASE_NAME=gradle 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0214915Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0215956Z D:\a\1\s>set APP_HOME=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\gradle\tools\gradle-4.10.2\bin\.. 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0218701Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0219469Z D:\a\1\s>set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS= 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0219796Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0219957Z D:\a\1\s>if defined JAVA_HOME goto findJavaFromJavaHome 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0220081Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0220254Z D:\a\1\s>set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0220379Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0220524Z D:\a\1\s>set JAVA_EXE=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java.exe 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0220702Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0220889Z D:\a\1\s>if exist "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java.exe" goto init 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0232306Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0232903Z D:\a\1\s>if not "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" goto win9xME_args 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0244450Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0244782Z D:\a\1\s>set CMD_LINE_ARGS= 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0244811Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0245082Z D:\a\1\s>set _SKIP=2 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0253055Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0254920Z D:\a\1\s>if "x-p" == "x" goto execute 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0255086Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0255825Z D:\a\1\s>set CMD_LINE_ARGS=-p D:\a\1\s\platforms\android wrapper -b D:\a\1\s\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0265584Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0266861Z D:\a\1\s>set CLASSPATH=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\gradle\tools\gradle-4.10.2\bin\..\lib\gradle-launcher-4.10.2.jar 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0274592Z 
2018-12-03T15:18:52.0274791Z D:\a\1\s>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java.exe"    "-Dorg.gradle.appname=gradle" -classpath "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\gradle\tools\gradle-4.10.2\bin\..\lib\gradle-launcher-4.10.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain -p D:\a\1\s\platforms\android wrapper -b D:\a\1\s\platforms\android\wrapper.gradle 
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6206198Z 
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6270697Z Welcome to Gradle 4.10.2!
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6271253Z 
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6271631Z Here are the highlights of this release:
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6272029Z  - Incremental Java compilation by default
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6272386Z  - Periodic Gradle caches cleanup
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6272910Z  - Gradle Kotlin DSL 1.0-RC6
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6273668Z  - Nested included builds
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6273707Z  - SNAPSHOT plugin versions in the `plugins {}` block
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6273733Z 
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6273788Z For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/release-notes.html
2018-12-03T15:19:00.6273814Z 
2018-12-03T15:19:05.6284429Z Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
2018-12-03T15:19:36.5285821Z > Task :wrapper
2018-12-03T15:19:36.5286311Z 
2018-12-03T15:19:36.5287212Z BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 43s
2018-12-03T15:19:36.5287360Z 1 actionable task: 1 executed
2018-12-03T15:19:36.9295864Z 
2018-12-03T15:19:36.9297284Z D:\a\1\s>if "0" == "0" goto mainEnd 
2018-12-03T15:19:36.9307635Z 
2018-12-03T15:19:36.9308179Z D:\a\1\s>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" endlocal
2018-12-03T15:27:41.2923310Z 2018-12-03T15:27:41.287Z ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: SIGINT received
2018-12-03T15:27:41.2989618Z 2018-12-03T15:27:41.289Z ionic:cli-framework:utils:process onBeforeExit handler: running 2 functions
2018-12-03T15:27:41.4164800Z ^C
2018-12-03T15:27:41.4203878Z 2018-12-03T15:27:41.416Z ionic:lib:shell Error in subprocess stdout pipe: Error: write after end at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:236:12) at Object.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:287:5) at Readable.write (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\stream-combiner2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:855:33) at Transform.ondata (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:635:20) at emitOne (events.js:116:13) at Transform.emit (events.js:211:7) at addChunk (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:301:12) at readableAddChunk (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:283:11) at Transform.Readable.push (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:247:10) at Transform.push (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:149:32)
2018-12-03T15:27:41.4207242Z 2018-12-03T15:27:41.417Z ionic:lib:shell Error in subprocess stderr pipe: Error: write after end at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:236:12) at Object.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:287:5) at Readable.write (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\stream-combiner2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:855:33) at Transform.ondata (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:635:20) at emitOne (events.js:116:13) at Transform.emit (events.js:211:7) at addChunk (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:301:12) at readableAddChunk (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:283:11) at Transform.Readable.push (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:247:10) at Transform.push (C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\taco_home\node_modules\ionic\4.5.0\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:149:32)
2018-12-03T15:27:41.4223196Z [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your nodejs already installed, your npm have kind of packages you need to build ionic3, sometimes in nodejs and npm is important to check your packages is done to install in your machine